# Insert table form another table with sum

Tags: sql

> INSERT INTO OrderProductStock (product_id, shop_id, product_qty)
> VALUES SELECT  o.product_id, o.shop_id,  SUM(o.product_qty), FROM
> OrderProduct o  LEFT JOIN MOrder m ON o.order_id=m.order_id  LEFT JOIN
> Product p ON o.product_id=p.product_id  WHERE m.order_status!=6 AND
> (m.is_online=0 OR (m.is_online=1 AND m.order_status=4)) AND
> o.shop_id=1 AND o.product_id=973 AND o.create_date < '2021-06-30
> 23:59:59'

I get follow remind but do not know what wrong.
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT  o.product_id, o.shop_id,
SUM(o.product_qty),
FROM    OrderProduct o
' at line 2

Answer (score 1):

change your query as per following

```
INSERT INTO OrderProductStock (product_id, shop_id, product_qty) VALUES 
SELECT o.product_id, o.shop_id, SUM(o.product_qty) As product_qty FROM
OrderProduct o LEFT JOIN MOrder m ON o.order_id=m.order_id LEFT JOIN Product 
p ON o.product_id=p.product_id WHERE m.order_status!=6 AND (m.is_online=0 OR 
(m.is_online=1 AND m.order_status=4)) AND o.shop_id=1 AND o.product_id=973 
AND o.create_date < '2021-06-30 23:59:59'
```